# In jmeter, can we use few parameters with in what we declared in the HTTP request parameter section

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In my case i have created one HTTP Request with all the possible parameter as below -
[image]

My .csv file is looking as below -
[image]

For some test case i need to send details in one or two parameter only, not for all. Now how can i do that in the same HTTP request without creating a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you can just send empty parameter values, just make sure that you have a blank value in the CSV file, i.e.:

```
param1,param2
foo,bar
baz,
,qux
```

[image]

Alternatively if you want to completely remove the parameters with empty values from the request you can add a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
def newData = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()

0.upto(sampler.getArguments().size() - 1, { idx ->
    def arg = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(idx)
    if (!arg.getValue().equals('')) {
        newData.addArgument(arg)
    }
})

sampler.setArguments(newData)
```

This way JMeter will remove the parameters which don't have their respective values from the request:

[image]

In the above example `sampler` stands for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html), see the JavaDoc for all available functions decriptions

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the help. After adding the JSR223 PreProcessor it works